# Crash log is not completely symbolicated

Tags: ios, symbolicatecrash

I am able to symbolicate my crash logs in xcode 4.5 EXCEPT for the last line.  Specifically line 29 of the 'Last Exception Backtrace'  and line 15 in the 'Thread 0' area in the crash log doesn't show the object or method call when all the other lines do.  My code is CoachMe1.

Any ideas as to why this would be ?

Here is the Symbolicated code:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3165929e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x355af97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x316591c0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
3   Foundation                      0x34a9ece2 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:] + 2402
4   CoachMe1                        0x000047b6 -[CoachMe1ViewController viewWillAppear:] (CoachMe1ViewController.m:322)
5   UIKit                           0x32b7531c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 132
6   UIKit                           0x32b817a0 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 536
7   UIKit                           0x32b814ac -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 320
8   UIKit                           0x32b6fb8e -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 854
9   UIKit                           0x32b6f82e -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 34
10  CoachMe1                        0x000183da -[FrontPageViewController loadGameDashboard] (FrontPageViewController.m:38)
11  UIKit                           0x32bf90a8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
12  UIKit                           0x32bf905a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
13  UIKit                           0x32bf9038 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
14  UIKit                           0x32bf88ee -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
15  UIKit                           0x32bf8de4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
16  UIKit                           0x32b215f4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
17  UIKit                           0x32b0e804 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
18  UIKit                           0x32b0e11e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
19  GraphicsServices                0x3085459e _PurpleEventCallback + 586
20  GraphicsServices                0x308541ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3162e16e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3162e112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3162cf94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3159feb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3159fd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
26  GraphicsServices                0x308532e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
27  UIKit                           0x32b622fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
28  CoachMe1                        0x0000257e main (main.m:14)
29  CoachMe1                        0x00002538 0x1000 + 5432


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3934f350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33cb111e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ced96e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30803d4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30800ff4 _ZL17default_terminatev + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x355afa74 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30801078 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30801110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30802594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x355af9cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3159ff1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3159fd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x308532e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x32b622fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  CoachMe1                        0x0000257e main (main.m:14)
15  CoachMe1                        0x00002538 0x1000 + 5432
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing in `loadGameDashboard` function in `FrontPageViewController.m` class line 38.

Please check this function with a break point . you see where your app is crashing....

Comment: Yes, thanks I found that.  I guess the last line, line 29 is less important than I thought.  Still not clear why that line is not symbolicated.  Is that normal?  Thanks